# Show Admin value of an attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

In Magento 1.x I could show the Admin value of an Attribute like this:

```
_product->getAdminAttributeText('bleach')
```

But it doesn't work in Magento 2. How can I show the Admin value of a dropdown list in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this (maybe not the cleanest):

```php
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object and load the product using id.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Mode\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Get the value using option id.

```
$optionId = 10;
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
   $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I get the ID number and how do I output the value?

Comment: option ID can be fetched using inspect element

Answer (score 0):

To get the admin value of an attribute, try this :

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME');
$adminValue = $attribute
              ->setStoreId(0) // Admin store ID
              ->getSource()->getOptionText($product->getData('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME'));
```